# access application_helper in before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I have the following in my application_helper.rb file:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def require_employer_profile_for_employers(page)
        if current_user.type == 'Employer'
            if current_user.employer_profile
            else
                flash[:error] = "You must create a profile before accessing #{page}."
                redirect_to new_employer_profile_path
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I try calling it in my projects controller like this:

```
before_action "require_employer_profile_for_employers('Projects')"
```

but my server responds with this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `require_employer_profile_for_employers' for #<ProjectsController:0x007fb741f82e38>):
```

How do I access the helper in the before_action in the projects controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

include `ApplicationHelper` in your `ProjectsController`:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper 
    # ... 
end
```

Helpers are not directly accessible within a controller as opposed to view layer where they are freely accessible.